# How to distinguish between a coordinate bond and a covalent bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, coordination-compounds

I’m confused as I am unable to find a completely trusted way of finding coordinately bonded compounds from a bunch of other compounds.

Comment: Please don’t use all-caps in titles (or in the body or anywhere else, for all that matters) Thanks @Wild kitty for being quicker in editing ;)

Comment: Thnx @Wild kitty for being quicker in editing ;)

Comment: Coordinate bonds are covalent bonds and don't really differ in practice from non-coordinate ones. Only difference is source of electrons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coordinate bonds can be distinguished from (other or ‘normal’) covalent ones experimentally.

Let’s look at the bond creation first as [Newbie suggested](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/39308). Typically, one would use a Lewis base and a Lewis acid to create a coordinate bond between them.

$$\ce{NH3 + BH3 -> H3N\bond{->}BH3}\tag{1}$$

In contrast, one would usually consider a normal covalent bond to be created from two radicals:

$$\ce{H3C^{.} + {}^{.}CH3 -> H3C-CH3}\tag{2}$$

But we can also create covalent $\ce{C-C}$ bonds by using a carbanion source and a carbocation source (slightly different example, because both ions are actually known and react with each other):

$$\ce{(H3C)3C+ + {}^{-}CN -> (H3C)3C-CN}\tag{3}$$

Thus, we can’t really tell a difference here. The difference in fact lies in the way a bond *dissociates* if the bond dissociation enthalpy $D = \Delta_\mathrm{D} H^0$ is provided. Standard covalent bonds will dissociate *homolytically* by the following equation:

$$\ce{H3C-CH3 -> H3C^. + ^.CH3}\tag{4}$$

A coordinate bond will, however, dissociate *heterolytically* thus liberation the original Lewis acid and base:

$$\ce{H3N\bond{->}BH3 -> NH3 + BH3}\tag{5}$$

In cases such as the ammonium ion ($\ce{NH4+}$) or say $\ce{[AlCl4]-}$ this means we have a certain number of normal bonds and another certain number of coordinate bonds (three and one, respectively in both examples). Although they are all between the same atoms, we *can* distinguish if we remember that neither ion can exist by itself, there will always be a corresponding counterion. Thus, if we consider $\ce{NH4Cl}$ or $\ce{Na[AlCl4]}$, we realise how the *first* bond is broken differently:

$$\begin{align}\ce{NH4Cl &-> NH3 + HCl}\tag{6}\\[0.6em]
\ce{Na[AlCl4] &-> NaCl + AlCl3}\tag{7}\end{align}$$

And all further bonds are cleaved *homolytically.* We gain two different bond dissociation energies, one corresponding to the coordinate bond and one corresponding to the remaining bonds. (Note that salts such as $\ce{AlCl3}$ or $\ce{NaCl}$ are cleaved homolytically by heating in the gas phase — flame-colouring would not happen if we had $\ce{Na+}$ in the flame.)

Comment: Firstly, you seem to be talking about "covalent bond" and "dative covalent bond" as two distinct types of bonds, which is not the case as one is a subset of the other (specifically "dative covalent" is a subset of "covalent").

Comment: Secondly, you also seem to misinterpret "covalent bond" as the pure covalent case (i.e. the bond is not polarised; the electronegativity difference between the two atoms involved is negligble).

Comment: Consider the case of the hydrohalic acids. They have been cited in many literature as "covalent substances". By your definition of homolytic fission, the bonds in these chemical species would not be "covalent" because they often dissociate to give ions. By your definition, wouldn't these bonds be considered "coordinate" and not "covalent".

Comment: In conclusion, your answer is problematic. These clarify your answer regarding the points I have raised.

Comment: @TanYongBoon The fallacy of your penultimate comment: I explicitly said *upon addition of the bond dissociation enthalpy.* This is not the case for deprotonation reactions; the bond is not broken by the bond dissociation enthalpy but by a certain reaction mechanism which involves breaking and reforming of bonds.

Comment: Also, you seem to be seeing covalent bonds as something ‘pure’ or somehow different from polarised covalent bonds (or ionic bonds). They are not; all bonds are some variation of a wave function. All we can do is pick out certain cases and attempt to interpret them with our models. Argument in point: even the ionic NaCl bond dissociates *homolytically* (as mentioned at the end of the answer) much like any covalent bond, proving it is much closer to a covalent bond than to a dative or coordinate bond.

Comment: I completely understand the different types of covalent bonds. My point of contention is your view of "covalent" as the "pure covalent" type, based on how you have defined it in your answer. I cannot be certain but I do not think that all covalent bonds would homolytically cleave upon addition of the bond enthalpy. Do you have any evidence to support your point?

Comment: Regarding the fallacy you have pointed out in your first comment, I admit that I have overlooked that phrase. However, the fact remains that you clearly have distinguished the "covalent bond" and the "coordinate bond" as two distinct types of bonds in your answer.

Comment: If you are not convinced, consider the following argument derived from your answer: Conclusion 1 (C1): Coordinate bonds heterolytically dissociate (upon addition of BDE). Conclusion 2 (C2): Covalent bonds homolytically dissociate (upon addition of BDE). However, let's now add in the general understanding of coordinate bonds as covalent bonds: Premise 1 (P1): Coordinate bonds are dative bonds. Conclusion 3 (C3: Based on C2 and P1): Coordinate bonds dissociate homolytically. As can be seen, there is a contradiction between C1 and C3 contradict when we factor in P1.

Comment: @TanYongBoon Ah, that’s where you’re coming from. Note that a coordiante (covalent) bond or dative bond or whatever you may call it is a bond very similar to an ordinary covalent bond but which dissociates heterolytically as outlined in my answer. This is a subset of covalent bonds that behaves differently from all other covalent (and ionic) bonds. Unfortunately, no word exists to the best of my knowledge to describe covalent non-dative bonds. Until it is created, I’ll have to live with the ambiguity of the term *covalent*.

Comment: @TanYongBoon A quick and dirty reference for dissociation energies and that they refer to homolytical dissociation is [the BDE Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy).

Comment: My contention is not in the terminology. Even after clarifying that the "covalent bond" in your answer is the "non-dative covalent bond", your answer remains problematic. Consider covalent substances like hydrogen fluoride do they dissociate to give a hydrogen radical and a fluorine radical **upon addition of BDE** or will it more likely give hydrogen and fluoride ions.

Comment: By your definition, do we then say the bond in hydrogen fluoride is a coordinate bond because it certainly would not homolytically cleave? If you agree with me on this, then your answer is indeed problematic.

Comment: In my opinion, you seem to be distinguishing the difference between a polarised bond and a pure covalent bond in your answer, and not the difference between a coordinate covalent bond and a non-coordinate covalent bond.

Comment: @TanYongBoon It seems to me that in lieu of experimental evidence you immediately assume that addition of the BDE to a compound such as hydrogen fluoride would result in heterolytic bond cleavage. That is not the case; e.g. irradiating $\ce{HF}$ molecules with light of the appropriate wavelength will generate hydrogen radicals and fluorine radicals.

Comment: All right, you are right in saying that I am making an assumption here regarding hydrogen fluoride. Therefore, any conclusions derived from that example may be false. So let's not talk  about that. Since I cannot be sure of a single non-coordinate covalent molecule like HF, how can you be sure that all non-coordinate covalent bonds would dissociate heterolytically? I am very sorry but I remain firm in my stance and am unconvinced by your answer.

Comment: @TanYongBoon I’ve noticed. I cannot convince you. Maybe reading up in the textbook of your choice convinces you =)

Comment: How about this? Which source(s) did you get this piece of information from?

Comment: @TanYongBoon Comments are not for prolonged discussions.

Answer (score 0):

The *main* (and probably the only) way is to apply the definition. In other way, you need to understand what the valence structures of the examined compound's ingredients are and based on this information to determine how they have bonded.

If you struggle to implement this analysis directly, try to work step by step, starting with thinking out a synthetic reaction, e.g.:

$$\ce{A + B -> AB}$$

that produces the examined compound $\ce{AB}$. The least you can conclude from knowing $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ is whether any of them provide elecro-deficient (or ionic) constituents of $\ce{AB}$, which, if so, is a clue that there may be coordinate bonding "in a close proximity" to the bond $\ce{A - B}$ …

*Example:* In ammonium hydroxide:

$$\ce{NH3 + H2O <=> NH4+ + OH-}$$

the hydroxide part is an anion, so it has a surplus of electrons. By knowing that $\ce{OH-}$ came from $\ce{H2O}$, it becomes obvious that the additional electron has came from one of the hydrogen atoms in $\ce{NH4+}$, hence, the bond between $\ce{N}$ and this particular $\ce{H+}$ is coordinate (both electrons come from the nitrogen atom $\ce{N}$).