Why in some covalent compounds, an element doesn't share any electrons?
Ok so i'm learning about compounds with an odd number of electrons and found weird scenarios like this:

NO2 is a covalent bond, because both of the elements are non-metals and don't have a huge electronegativity difference, and if you see the Oxygen on the left side there seems to be no problem, It is sharing 2 of his valence electron with 2 of the Nitrogen's valence electrons.
However if we see the Oxygen in the right side, it isn't sharing any of it's 6 valence eltrons with the Nitrogen, and yet it completes it's octect, implying that somehow, despite being in a covalent bond, the Nitrogen donated 2 of his valence electrons to oxygen, and something that seems to validate my point is that, despite only having 3 bonds, the Nitrogen lost 4 of Its 5 valence electrons an is left only with a free one, meaning that maybe It just donated 2 electrons to the Oxygen atom
My main 2 questions here are, Am I right to think this? and if so, How is this even possible?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76378/clarifying-the-concept-of-the-dative-covalent-bond https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10215/the-bond-in-coordination-complexes https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39293/how-to-distinguish-between-a-coordinate-bond-and-a-covalent-bond

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/why-does-coordinate-covalent-bond-form may be the dupe target here.

The oxygen has a negative charge. See structure of hydroxide very similar - there is no dative bond there

@user154560 It's nitrogen dioxide not nitrite.

The oxygene at right has a negative charge, and nitrogen has a positive. charge.

The question is : "Why an element does not share any electrons?" But the text of the question is about NO2. It never mentions elements that do not share electrons,,,,,

@Maurice I believe the text

However if we see the Oxygen in the right side, it isn't sharing any of it's 6 valence eltrons

Is mentioning where they believe there is no sharing with respect to $O$ on the right.

And we can see a prime example that dot structures are can be not only a waste of time, but also confusing.

@Marie_Korbel I'm also confused if you're speaking about $NO_2$ or $[NO_2^-]$?  One is a covalent compound and the other a polyatomic anion.

@Avogadro I was talking about NO2 not NO2-, I made this question because of my lack of knowledge of dative bonds, however now that i know about the subject i'll make my own research, Thanks for your time!

Odd electron species are hard to comprehend. You should always look at this with resonance. Bonding is still a tough cookie though…

$\ce{NO2}$ is particularly pernicious to diagram: it is a free radical: "the ground electronic state of nitrogen dioxide is a doublet state,... The lone electron in NO2 also means that this compound is a free radical, so the formula for nitrogen dioxide is often written as $\ce{^•NO2}$"
Note this diagram from Wikipedia, which emphasizes that each oxygen does not get full custody of a pair of nitrogen electrons:

